# Replace mixed content in XML (plain text + tags)

Tags: c#, xml

The program takes an xml that is mixture between html and custom tags. I want to replace this custom tag:

```
<replaceable />
```

With this:

```
Some text
<div>Other text</div>
```

The main problem is that any framework or library that I can use to properly handle XML (like LinqToXML or System.Xml) cannot get the whole content. If try like this:

```
// replaceable is an XElement for <replaceable />
// content is a string
replaceable.ReplaceWith(content)
```

It ends up all as escaped text, and is taken as the value for the XElement.

And if I try the XElement.Parse() method, like other questions here suggest, I lose the plain text at the beginning, and only the `<div>` remains.

Is there a way to do this kind of replacement without going all regex on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the content in a tag before you parse it, so that `XElement.Parse()` can give you all of the nodes.

```
var outer = XElement.Parse("<dummy>" + content + "</dummy>");
replaceable.ReplaceWith(outer.Nodes());
```

Comment: I am actually wrapping it. but this made me realize my silly mistake. I was using outer.Elements() instead of Nodes(). Thanks, that was fast and easy

Answer (score 0):

Using a string you are replacing the element with a text node.  You want to first create an new `XElement` and use it for replacement.

```
replaceable.ReplaceWith(new XElement("div", otherText));
```